# How can I solve PathTooLongException?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using (webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(result[i], filename);
}
```

The exception is:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

And when i'm looking on result(List) i see that the url in the first index 0 is very long. The question is if there is a way to solve it so it will accept long url's ?

Comment: What you have in filename?

Comment: @David Waters - This is NOT a duplicate. 1 is talking about the file system, and this one is talking about a web request. Thanks for locking a perfectly valid question.

Comment: This looks like it's the file name that is the problem, not the URL. 260 characters is the Windows limit for a file path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: [Delimon.Win32.I​O Library (V4.0)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-V40-7ff6b16c#content)

1. First add a reference to the Delimon.Win32.IO.dll to your project (Browse to the Delimon.Win32.IO.dll file)
2. In your Code File add "using Delimon.Win32.IO"
3. Use normal File & Directory Objects as if you are working with System.IO

It has its own versions of key methods from `System.IO`